# Execute task on deletion of an Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, scheduled-tasks

I want to remove the user's personal data from the database when they decide to delete the app from their device. I use WorkManager for some scheduled operations, but it doesn't seem to have a constraint that would satisfy that need.
Is there any way to run a piece of code right before the app gets deleted?

Comment: Are you looking to run the task on server or on the device itself?

Comment: "Is there any way to run a piece of code right before the app gets deleted?" -- fortunately, no, for security reasons.

Comment: @HardikKhandelwal I was thinking the device itself, but it can be on server as well, the goal is not to store the data for the users that no longer use the app

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you expand on this a little, please. Why is it a security concern?

Comment: Malware authors would be very, very happy for the opportunity to do things before their malware is uninstalled.

Comment: There's also a system Intent that's broadcast when an app is removed: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED Note that it specifically says the app being removed does *not* receive the Intent - this is by design

Comment: There are a few problems with automatic data removal anyway - what if the user temporarily removes the app, should they lose everything? What if they have the app on multiple devices, and remove it from one? You might want to consider just clearing data on your server for users who haven't been seen for a certain amount of time, and also give users the explicit option to delete their data in the Privacy section (which is also one of the things the Data Safety section on the Play Store asks about - it's a good thing to have!)

Comment: @cactustictacs That makes a lot of sense, thanks!